# What is a "grand slam single"?

Tags: baseball, mlb

MLB calls this a "grand slam single." How is that possible?

Comment: Is there any reason you haven't signed up for a full account? You seem to have created four or five different unregistered accounts by this point, which will make it impossible for you to track responses and answers to the questions you've posted previously.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In a tie game in extra innings and the home team is at bat, the game is over as soon as the winning run is scored. So even though the batter hit a homerun and the bases are loaded (hence a "grand slam"), once the runner crosses home plate and the batter reaches first, there's no reason for the other runners continuing. You can see the team celebrating with the batter in the field and because he didn't touch all the bases, so it was officially scored as a single.

Comment: The rule about the game ending immediately after the winning run scores was changed in 1920 to allow batters hitting a home run to be credited with a home run. Ventura was only credited with a single because he failed to run out the bases, not just because the winning run scored.

Answer (score 2):

"grand slam single" isn't an official term.  As the batter hit a home run with the bases loaded, he would normally be allowed to touch all the bases and have all 4 runners score (7.02(g)(3)).

But after the ball was struck, teammates came onto the field to celebrate and prevented him from continuing to second base.  You can see a quick shot Ventura waving to keep them away so he could finish, but they didn't depart.

Per the approved ruling, if the batter does something to cause him to be out (in this case 5.09(b)(2), abandoning an effort to touch the next base after having touched first base), then the game is over after the winning run scores.  The batter is credited with a single and (in this case) one RBI.